# beamerarticle: pause statement in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, lyx, animations, beamerarticle

I wonder how to use `\pause` in `tikz` with  `beamerarticle`. My MWE is below which throws errors. I know this code will work fine if I don't load `beamerarticle` with `beamer`. But I need to load `beamerarticle` with `beamer` to make handouts. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

### **Edited**

Would be sufficient for me if someone help me to disable `\pause` statements!!!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What should your output look like, if you don't want the normal `beamer` or `beamerarticle` output?

Comment: Thanks @JuriRobl for your interest in my problem. Actually I'm using `LyX` for my `beamer` slide. Then I use `beamerarticle` in `LyX` to make handouts. I want to stick with this protocol because I'm lazy user of `LaTeX`. Now I've `tikz` code in my `beamer` which works fine but the same code throws error with `beamerarticle`. If I delete `\pause` statement, every thing works fine.

Comment: If you compile it normally with `pdflatex` it doesn't work with `beamer` + `beamerarticle`, because they try to declare the same commands. Maybe `LyX` is doing something different internally?

Comment: @JuriRobl I suspect LyX is compiling in non-stop mode. If you plough through the errors, you do get a PDF in the end (at least if you comment out the `\pause` commands - I didn't test with them uncommented). Clearly a Bad Idea. But I can see why it might appear to work if LyX doesn't make the complaints obvious and/or you don't pay much attention to them. (I don't know if LyX does this or not.)

Comment: If you really want to do what you say, put `\gdef\pause{\relax}` after `\begin{document}`. Note that doing this is a terrible idea and you will still get error after error after error. You should use one of the solutions provided by `beamer` specifically for making handouts. Really. But this will get you a 'flat' result. What else it will do I am not prepared to even guess. Or put `\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}` *before* `\documentclass`. This is just as ugly and will produce equally horrible errors but will also flatten things.

Comment: @cfr `\let\pause=\relax` may be better, as in contrast to `\gdef` it is not expanded on every call. It may save you some milliseconds.

Comment: @HenriMenke You're right. I actually tried that first and then tried `\gdef` when it didn't work. But I think it was because I had it in the wrong place initially.

Comment: @cfr You can also `\global\let\pause=\relax` if you're unsure of grouping in a particular case.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. I actually tried that. But it didn't work when I placed it before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @cfr Maybe `\pause` is defined in `\AtBeginDocument` or things like that. Then all efforts are futile. `:-)` (This is my last comment. I don't want to exaggerate the discussion.)

Answer (score 5):

Don't load `beamerarticle` with `beamer`, but load it with an article-class (`article`, `scrartcl`, etc.).

`beamerarticle` is used to "convert" a presentation into a normal article. To do that it declares the same commands as `beamer`, that's why all commands are already declared and why you can't use both together.

Comment: Thanks @Juri for your answer. I need `beamerarticle` with `beamer` to make handouts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Have you tried the `handout` option `beamer` provides? Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, you cannot use `beamerarticle` with the `beamer` class. Compile interactively or look at the log/output to see the errors this produces. You can ignore these and get a PDF but things are going to go awry in subtle, and not so subtle, ways if you do that. Besides, there are better options:

## Handout Mode

Here is the effect of using `beamer`'s `handout` mode:

[image: handout mode]

That is, all slides on a frame are 'flattened' to produce a single snapshot of the completed frame.

### The Code

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Article Mode

If you want to produce a more traditional handout which doesn't look like slides at all, you can use `beamerarticle`, as others have pointed out, with the class of your choice. For example:

[image: article mode]

### The Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\mode<article>{
\section{This is only in the article}

\kant[1]
}

\section{In all modes}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Presentation Mode

Note that replacing the `article` class with `beamer` and commenting `\usepackage{beamerarticle}` puts you in 'regular' `beamer` mode with all the bells and whistles used in presentations. That is, essentially the same code:

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass{beamer}
% \usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}

\mode<article>{
\section{This is only in the article}

\kant[1]
}

\section{In all modes}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces quite different output:

[image: presentation mode]

## Handout Mode Revisited

One problem with the standard `handout` produced by `beamer` is that it is not very efficient in terms of paper. If your presentation has 10 or 20 slides, you do not really need 10 or 20 pages in your handout. The solution suggested in the manual is to use `pgfpages` which avoids the need for a separate source file. This allows you to display several frames on one page. Suppose, for example, you have four frames rather than one in green, blue and yellow as well as red. In conjunction with `handout` mode, `pgfpages` allows you to produce something like this:

[image: handout mode revisited]

### The Code

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
% \usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfstroke}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfstroke}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfstroke}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfstroke}

\begin{document}

\mode<article>{
\section{This is only in the article}

\kant[1]
}

\section{In all modes}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[red, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[blue, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[blue, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[green, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[green, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow, very thick] (0.35, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[yellow, very thick] (1.65, -5.35) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.25cm);
    \pause
    \draw[yellow, very thick] (3.7, -5.25) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Other Options

There are other possibilities. For example, if you don't mind having an additional source file, you can use `pdfpages` rather than `pgfpages` to put multiple frames on a single page. (This is the option I tend to use most for handouts.)

Moreover, you can load a different theme to produce your handout e.g. one suitable for printing on a black-and-white printer or for photocopying.