# An Introduction to LaTeX in beamer documentclass in TeX format

Tags: beamer, document-classes

Sorry if this is a off topic or duplicate question. I'm looking for `An Introduction to LaTeX`  in `beamer` `documetclass` in `tex` format. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

---

**Edited**

---

I'm looking for a document in Tex format similar to [this one](http://cs.au.dk/~adc/files/LaTeX-Presentation.pdf). So that I don't have to type everything.

Comment: [Simple Beamer Template for Total Beginners](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102791)

Comment: @cmhughes: I don't think my question is duplicate of [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102791/4821](Simple Beamer Template for Total Beginners). That question is about beamer template, however, my question is about `An Introduction to LaTeX` in `beamer` style in `TeX` format so that I don't have to type `An Introduction to LaTeX` in `beamer`.

Comment: So, you are looking for a handbook/manual to LaTeX that is already written with the `beamer` class, so you don't have to write it but can still modify it? Then your question would not be a duplicate, but I am not sure it belongs here either (it is not a TeX question, it is a "make-my-life-easier" one). Why can't you just take an existing presentation and state it as not being your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Nicola Talbot has written some material for an introductory LaTeX course; the material can be found in [`An Introduction to LaTeX`](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/csed/). There, you can find the PDF documents: the handout, the slides (made using `beamer`) and some additional notes. The source files are also available.
2. Another resource can be found in the UK-TUG. Nicola Talbot and Joseph Wright periodically offer a LaTeX course. In this [`UK_TUG page`](http://uk.tug.org/2010/07/30/training-day-a-success/), You'll find links to the material for the course. PDFs are available as well as the source code for the slides (produced using `beamer`).

Comment: Thanks a lot @GonaloMedina for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've another question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163830/4821). Is there any way to disable `\pause` statement in `tikz`? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a good starting point and for `beamer` it is self explanatory as well. If you are using Linux open up the terminal else in Windows open the Command Prompt and type `texdoc beamer`. The documentation file will be displayed. Its a good starting point. To start off: 
Beamer class is used to generate **slides** for presentation purposes. There is another class named `slides` but, `beamer` has more features and widely used. A sample document will look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Introduction to Beamer}
\author{Subham Soni S.}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{This is my first slide} %The second argument is title of the frame
\section{First slide} %This is used to make the title appear in the Table of Contents - Note:- Not Necessary that the frame title and Section title should be same.
Hello Everyone. You are viewing the \emph{first} slide.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{This is my second slide}
\section{Second slide}
Hello Everyone. You are viewing the \emph{second} slide.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answers the question (see the edit at the end of the question).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think It would have been better if there had been an MWE.